Donkey pump is centrifugal or positive displacement?
Donkey pump belong to which category of pumps?Is it centrifugal or positive displacement? According to my understanding it is positive displacement. Please correct me if i am not right
I have also attached image of donkey pump


The image you show is a double acting piston pump, so yes it's positive displacement.
